# How to fix choppy fonts after using KDE System Settings?

Tags: gnome, kde, fonts

I used KDE System Settings to configure my KDE appearance settings (I wanted to make KolourPaint look native), even though I use GNOME. I changed some font settings through it, and now all of my fonts are really choppy. Is there any way to revert these changes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All font settings are stored in a hidden file in your home folder, called .fonts.conf.

If you remove it (in your home folder, press **Ctrl + H**, and delete .fonts.conf), and generate a new one, by running, in a terminal instance (**Applications > Accessories > Terminal**):
 `sudo dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig`

You then should get the usual Linux crystal clear fonts (you actually may need to log out and log back in, but that's it)

Comment: Thank you very much. This solved my problem. I honestly can't believe I didn't think of it myself.