# KDE appearance broken after using systemsettings

Tags: themes, kde, fonts

On Ubuntu 14.04 (Unity) I wanted to change some KDE appearance settings, so I installed systemsettings. This turned out to be a bad idea, since it made the fonts in KDE applications ugly (see [How to fix choppy fonts after using KDE System Settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15010/how-to-fix-choppy-fonts-after-using-kde-system-settings); unfortunately the solution there didn't work for me). I tried deleting KDE configuration files but this just made it worse, resetting the theme as well to the blue KDE default.

My question is, how do I reset KDE appearance settings to look like they're supposed to on Ubuntu? I guess Ubuntu ships its own configuration files, and if so, where do I get them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most settings are stored in the `~/.kde/share/config/` directory. Try moving it somewhere and restarting your session.

Comment: Thanks. This didn't actually work; I had already tried it. For some reason, however, deleting the new `~/.kde/` folder that had been generated and then moving the old one back into place fixed the problem. Maybe I needed to keep this one in place and just move the various other KDE configuration files I moved.